# Template problems

Tags: c++, templates

I have this simple sort program which should work for vector of `Set<int>`-s , it works for primitive types and I use some other compare functions for non primitives and it works well, but once I try to compare sets it crashes with error:

> `error C2782: 'void Sort(Vector<ElemType> &,int (__cdecl *)(type,type))' : template parameter 'type' is ambiguous`

How can I fix this?

```
template <typename type>
void swap(int &a, int &b){
    type tmp =a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}


template <typename type>
void Sort(Vector<type>& vec,int (cmp) (type,type) = OperatorCmp ){
    while(true){
        for(int i =1; i < v.size(); i++){
        if(cmp(v[i-1],v[i]) > 0){
           break;
            }else{
            return;
         }
    }

        int index1 = RandomInteger(0,vec.size()-1);
        int index2 = RandomInteger(0,vec.size()-1);
        swap(vec[index1],vec[index2]);
    }
}


int main(){
    Randomize();
    Vector<char>a;

    Sort(a);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think deduction can work here.

Comment: This is nowhere near a **minimum**, **complete** example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does. It just yields inconsistent deductions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type mismatch. `bozoSort` is declared as:

```
template <typename T>
void bozoSort(Vector<T>& vec, int (cmp) (T,T) );
```

When you call it with `a`, you are hoping to deduce `T = Set<int> >`, which would be the signature:

```
void bozoSort(Vector<Set<int> >& vec, int (cmp) (Set<int>, Set<int> ));
```

However, you're calling it with `compareSets`, which has the signature `int (Set<int>&, Set<int>&)`. Those don't match, so the compiler can't resolve the template for you. The better solution would be just to take the whole comparator as a template:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare>
void bozoSort(Vector<T>& vec, Compare cmp) { ... }
```

That way, if you want your comparator to take its arguments by reference, const reference, or value - any of the above will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

`type` is deduced as a reference to `Set<int>` for the function pointer parameter and `Set<int>` for the value type of the container, which is an inconsistent deduction. The easiest solution: Completely generalize the functor:

```
template <typename type, typename Fun>
bool isSorted(Vector<type> & vec, Fun cmp){
    for(int i =0; i < vec.size()-1; i++){
        if(cmp(vec[i],vec[i+1]) > 0)return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

.. and overload for the one-parameter case.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
template <typename type>
void bozoSort(Vector<type>& vec,int (cmp) (type,type) = OperatorCmp )
```

and you are calling it with

```
vec = Vector<Set<int>>
```

and

```
cmp = compareSets
```

which is

```
int compareSets(Set<int>& a , Set<int>& b){
```

Now for `vec`, `type` can only be `Set<int>`, while for `cmp`, `type` can only be `Set<int>&`. Both don't go together, hence the error.